# Groovy script to get translations using Google Translate API gives java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, groovy, google-api, google-translate, google-api-java-client

I am trying to write a Groovy script to get translations from Google Translate API (using an API key, stored in as the GOOGLE_API_KEY environment variable1) but I get an error I'm not able to overcome. The Groovy script runs in [OmegaT](https://omegat.org), which is a Java application.

References: [Google Translate's API documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/java-translate) and the code in [Google APIs' Github repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/main/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/translate/snippets/DetectLanguageAndTranslate.java).

This is my script:

```java
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='com.google.cloud', module='google-cloud-translate', version='2.1.13')
])

import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;

// api key is stored in the GOOGLE_API_KEY environment variable 
Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

String translation = translate.translate("Hello world", 
          TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"), 
          TranslateOption.targetLanguage("es"));

console.println(translation); // "Hola mundo"
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
The script "/home/pico/.omegat/scripts/mt_google.groovy" is running...
An error occurred
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
```

I've read online that this can be caused by a dependency conflict and that it might be related to guava. I have tried excluding that library like this (at the top of the script), but to no avail:

```java
@GrabExclude(group='com.google.guava', module='guava')
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

---

### UPDATE:

From the source code folder of the Java application inside which my Groovy script runs I can generate a tree of Guava dependencies, like so:

```
> ./gradlew dependencies | grep guava
     +--- com.google.guava:guava:23.6-jre
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:15.0 -> 16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:15.0 -> 16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0
```

I can share the full list without grepping but it's a long list.

I have now tried with the following section at the top of my script:

```java
@Grapes([
    @GrabExclude(group='com.google.guava', module='guava', version='16.0.1'),
    @Grab(group='com.google.cloud', module='google-cloud-translate', version='2.1.13')
])
```

but then I get error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/MoreObjects`.

Comment: There should be hall of fame for number of distinct Guava dependencies in a project! Guava is widely used and the issue is usually multiple versions. I think you don't want to exclude Guava, you want to try excluding older versions. Are you able to derive a dependency graph? That should help you identify what you're getting.and should give you a more precise knife. I'm unfamiliar with Groovy but remember encountering simillar issues with Java on App Engine.

Comment: Thanks,  @DazWilkin. I don't know how to generate the dependency graph from the script, but I've cloned the [repository with the source code](https://github.com/omegat-org/omegat) of the Java application where my script runs, and ran `./gradlew dependencies`  there. Does this help?

Comment: I think so.... The latest Guava version is 19 which includes  `com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.`[`directExecutor`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#directExecutor()). It appears that `directExecutor` arrived after v17.0 [`directExecutor`](https://guava.dev/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#directExecutor()) (it's not present here). So, can you try excluding the v16|v15 versions and forcing v18|v19?

Comment: Looks like google-cloud-translate depends on guava 31.1-jre. All the other versions in the dependency tree should be overridden. No need for Grapes wrapper any longer. And GrabExclude would go outside of it anyways. Do you have a stack trace where the NoSuchMethod is coming from?  Lots of the transitive dependencies require guava and may be using an older method not part of 31.1-jre

Comment: I have tried running the script as `groovy script.groovy` (in the command line with Java 17) with `@Grapes([ @Grab(group='com.google.guava', module='guava', version='31.1-jre'), @Grab(group='com.google.cloud', module='google-cloud-translate', version='2.2.0')])` and it runs fine.  However, I still get the errors I mentioned when I run it from inside the Java application (run on Java 11).

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/ZFy2ZrWQ) is the full error.